# JMS implementation using JNDI in spring application

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, jms, jndi

I am trying to implement JMS in my spring application. I have defined the JNDI name + queue name in applicationContext.xml as follows:

```
<bean id="emailQueueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jms/<<Name of JNDI of connection factory>>" />
</bean>

<bean id="emailQueueDestination" class="org.springframework`enter code here`.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jms/<<JNDI name of queue>>" />
</bean>

<bean id="emailQueueTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" lazy-init="true">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="emailQueueConnectionFactory" />
<property name="defaultDestination" ref="emailQueueDestination" />
</bean>

<bean id="emailSender" class="<<Package>>.EmailSender" lazy-init="true">
<property name="jmsTemplate">
<ref bean="emailQueueTemplate" />
</property>
</bean>
```

Now my controller makes a call to the emailSender bean using the following code:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");
EmailSender sender =(EmailSender)context.getBean("emailSender");
```

The exception I get is: Error 404: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

I am loading the applicationContext.xml at serevr start-up still my code is not able to locate this file.

Can anyone please help.??

Answer (score 0):

make sure your applicationContext.xml file is in your class path then add the class path prefix, You can try some thing like this

```
   ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:applicationContext.xml");
```

Comment: Hey..thanks for ur reply.
However in my application we do not include the applicationContext.xml in classpath as of now.It gets loaded with web.xml.So my concern is , is it really necessary to include it in my classpath since its a pretty old application and we are nt following that practice as of now.

Comment: I am guessing it is located under WEB-INF folder, The question if context file is being loaded in web.xml (either by loader listener or dispatch servlet), Why do u need to load again? If you are using spring controller why is the EmailSender not injected?

Comment: hey..I did the same...since applicatoncontext.xml was getting loaded at server startup..., I just injected my bean in the controller rather than loading the applicationContext again. and it worked for me perfectly fine.... Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Hi, is it necessary to save the message we send in session. If i simply generate my xml and pass it to the send method, can this cause a problem..